# c# - regular expression to remove [youtube ] from the wordpress post content

Tags: c#, regex, wordpress

I have this regular expression that removes html :

sr.Text = Regex.Replace(sr.Text, @"<[^>]*>", "");

what should be the regex to remove both html and

[youtube width="610" height="343"]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w_BPwoPbghw&hd=1[/youtube]

from the post content ?

Thanks !

Comment: 1) What have you tried? 2) Pleas edit the question and tag the language you're using.

Comment: I tried to include the youtube tag to the regex above :  sr.Text = Regex.Replace(sr.Text, @"</?youtube[^>]*?>", ""); - didn't work !

Comment: No - I mean what language are you doing this REGEX in? PHP? Java?

Comment: I added the language to the the question :) C# !

Comment: Solved it ! 

 sr.Text = Regex.Replace(sr.Text, @"\[youtube.*\[\/youtube\]", "");

Comment: I was unable to answer earlier, since the requirement was to have more than x comments, worked now.  newbie here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by trying [youtube.*[/youtube]
there's width and height after [youtube

Final code :  sr.Text = Regex.Replace(sr.Text, @"[youtube.*[/youtube]", "");